# vue.js - unable to change the state of the message

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following message in my login.vue

```
<p v-if="registered" class="greenbg white p-3 text-justify">
       {{message}}
 </p>
```

I have the following data property

```
         data(){
            return{

                email: '',
                password: '',
                role: 'issuer',
                message: this.$store.state.message,
                registered: this.$store.state.registered
                
            }
        }
```

I have used

```
this.$store.dispatch('ilogin',{//some data for verification})
```

In store index.js i have an action of sending a get request.

```
  actions: {

  ilogin({commit},authData){

        axios.post('/login', {
        //some data
      })
      .then((res) => {

        //do something
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        commit('noauthUser',{
          message: error.response.data.message
        })
        
        
      })
  }
}
```

In mutation section i have the following mutation

```
  mutations: {


         noauthUser(state, noauthData){

         state.message = noauthData.message,
         state.registered = true
  
     }

 
   }
```

i am unable to show the message though the vue developer tool says the value has been updated.
[image]

Any particular reason for this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data in the store may change, you need to define `message` and `registered` as computed properties. You can also use mapGetters:

`computed: mapGetters(['message', 'registered'])`

Don't forget to import `mapGetters` from Vuex

Comment: Hi. it worked. can you let me know what was the flaw in my approach

Comment: Yes. As I said, when you set it inside the data method instead of as a computed property, you basically hardcode the value into the current state. This means any changes won't be reflected. This is the reason you need to use a computed property. The mapGetters method is just a convenient way to automatically map them into computed properties.